# Считывание файлов из INPUT с помощью JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос из темы конченная наркомания, но прошу понять и простить

```
//имею
input type=files + JQ код, который отслеживает изменения в нем

//при изменении - вывести файлы в консоль
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    console.log(this.files);
});
```

Хочется переделать алгоритм, что бы при нажатии на кнопку считывались файлы

```
//при нажатии на кнопку - вывести файлы в консоль ( код не рабочий )
$(".chat_load_file").click(function(){
    console.log($('input[type=file]').prop('files'));
});
```

В моем случае в консоль ничего не выводит, ест-но выбрать файлы в INPUT перед этим не забыл. От сюда вопрос, как подобное без ошибок организовать

Comment: При событии change заполняете переменную файлами. При нажатии на кнопку считываете эти файлы с переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".chat_load_file").click(function(){
    var inputs = $('input[type=file]');
    inputs.each(function() {
      console.log("this", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<input type="file">
<button class="chat_load_file">Click me</button>
```